# Why doesn't the text on this Label Align correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm trying to make the text on this label be on the center of it:

```
 label = new Label();
 label.Text = "A";
 label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
 label.AutoSize = false;
 label.Size = LabelSize;
 label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

But this is the result:

[image]

Comment: It seems the size of label is less than the height which a character in the selected font can be. For example see this string: `ﺃAﺇ`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!